# Missing Wine Program Folder in Xubuntu 14.04-LTS

Tags: xubuntu, wine, xfce, menu

After installing Wine 1.6.2 from the Ubuntu Software Center the Program folder with the installed Windows programs is not shown in XFCE menu. Only the following enteries are shown:

- Deinstall Wine Application
- Search C:
- Configure Wine
- Winetricks

When I start Alacarte the wine menu shows all program menus and they are marked.

Why are the wine program menu entries not shown on in the Xfce Application Menu?

---

**Content of `/home/USER/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu`**:

```
MergeFile type="parent"/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/menus/xfce-applications.menu</MergeFile>
AppDir/home/USER/.local/share/applications/AppDir
```

`/home/USER/.config/menus/applications-merged`

*contains all wine-Programs.menu files*

`/home/USER/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs`

*contains the .desktop folders and files of the installed windows programs*

`/home/USER/.local/share/desktop-directories`

*contains all wine .directory files*

Comment: Could you post the contents of one `.desktop` file of a Wine program that is not showing up in the menu?

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently due to a larger bug in the applications menu. In order for a folder to show, it must have at least one launcher in it. Since the Wine "Programs" folder may install with only sub-folders, it isn't displayed (even if there are launchers in the sub-folders). See this bug report, and the workaround in the reply:

https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=10967

I had this problem on one machine, and not on one other. The one that showed the menu had installed Wine with a launcher for MS Access in the Programs folder. In the problem machine, there was no launcher. I added a launcher for a Windows program to the Programs folder, and now it is visible.